# How to unzip all zip folders in my subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zip

My folder structure

```
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter03/
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter05/
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter07/
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter09/
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter10/
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter13/
drwx------ 2 miki miki 4096 сеп 12  2018 Chapter14/
-rw-r--r-- 1 miki miki   96 сеп 12  2018 README.txt
```

Each chapter contains on ore more zip folders.
I tried this way

```
unzip -d $(find ./ -type f -name '*.zip')
```

This does not work.

```
Archive:  ./Chapter14/kops-master.zip
4ffc8d76f1313a2f2a04a87d543a0701816c3df7
checkdir:  cannot create extraction directory: ./Chapter14/weave-kube-master.zip
           File exists
```

How should the proper command look like?

Comment: The `-d` argument should be the directory, not the zip file. You code is doing something like `unzip -d my.zip`, which makes no sense. You need something like `unzip my.zip -d my_dir`. Or maybe just `unzip my.zip`. Also see [`unzip (1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
```

This runs `unzip` on each zip file found by your `find` command.

The above will work even if the zip files or directories have spaces or other difficult characters in their names.

Answer (score 0):

Since zip files may contain/nest zip files, and we do not know the order of files reading in the `find` command. It is better to run `find` command twice, or 3 times. Corresponding to the zip nesting level.

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
```